# JSPDF AUTOTABLE not displaying proper table Border

Tags: javascript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I want to export PDF with JSPDF and i m using plugin as "jspdf.autotable" for creating tables.now the problem is i want the formatting style like below:

[image]

As you can see there is a border outside the table but not in header part,i have achieved it but when the rows exceed the page height the formatting of table is not rendered properly.as autotable plugin don't have built in functionality to only have border outside of table.
I have another solution to add whole HTML in pdf but i dont want pictures as a tables.
please help with this ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had this problem too, unfortunately I didn't have the author to guide me, my bad I was not aware of stackoverflow back them. I had to go edit the library in order to achieve the desired result.

I had to make changes to `printRows()` method and place a check to check for the first page and the rest of the pages from where I needed the table to begin. As the first page would have extra margin for the graph.

I used the following in the `table.rows.forEach()` in the first if condition where it checks for the `isNewPage()` method :

```
if (pageCount == 1) {
    doc.setDrawColor(228, 228, 228);
    doc.rect(settings.margin.left, settings.startY + table.headerRow.height, table.width, row_height);
} else {
    doc.setDrawColor(228, 228, 228);
    doc.rect(settings.margin.left, settings.margin.top + table.headerRow.height + 30, table.width, row_height);
}
addPage();
```

These are the checks that I used, and are specific to my application, see if you can get an idea on how to implement the rest on your own.

Answer (score 3):

As the author of the plugin I can't think of a simply way to accomplish this unfortunately. The only thing that comes to mind is that you can try utilizing for example the `afterContent` hook and add a rectangle on each page that is a few pixels larger than the table. In effect emulating a border.

I have seen this feature request mentioned before however and I'm considering adding it in a future release. Not in the near term though.